# sh: 1: /etc/sbin/sendmail: not found php не отправляет почту

Tags: php

пытаюсь отправить письмо при помощи mail(). в консоль падает ошибка sh: 1: /etc/sbin/sendmail: not found. но я всё проверил, такой файл присутствует, к тому же стоит postfix. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: обычно полный путь должен быть `/usr/sbin/sendmail`

Comment: да, спасибо, это помогло